# Cohomology for Grassmannian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

For the Grassmannian $\mathbb{G}(l,V)$ one has for the dual tautological bundle $\mathcal{Q^{\vee}}$: $\mathrm{Hom}(\sum^{\lambda}(\mathcal{Q}^{\vee}),\sum^{\mu}(\mathcal{Q}^{\vee}))=\sum^{(\mu/\lambda)}V^*$. What do we have for $\mathrm{Hom}(\sum^{\lambda}(\mathcal{Q}),\sum^{\mu}(\mathcal{Q}))$?

Answer (score 3):

$\mathrm{Hom}(\Sigma^\lambda(Q^*), \Sigma^\mu(Q^*))\simeq\mathrm{Hom}(\Sigma^\mu(Q), \Sigma^\lambda(Q))$ as $\Sigma^\lambda(Q^*)\simeq (\Sigma^\lambda(Q))^*$.